# ArrayList String to int sorting order

Tags: java, selenium, sorting, arraylist, int

I need to verify Ascending sorting order tab is working. 
But when I compare the result its not working due to single and double digit number. 
How can I convert ArrayList to int ? will that work

```
        ArrayList<String> obtainedList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-table//mat-row/mat-cell[2]"));
    for (WebElement we : elementList) {
        obtainedList.add(we.getText());
    }
    // This is where I should convert array to int ?

    ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : obtainedList) {
        sortedList.add(s);
    }

    Collections.reverse(sortedList);
    Collections.sort(sortedList);

    Reporter.log(AddRule + obtainedList + sortedList + " Cloumn is display in  Ascending order");
    Add_Log.info(AddRule + obtainedList + sortedList + " Cloumn is display in  Ascending order");
    List<String> labels = elementList.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
    SortedSet<String> sorted = new TreeSet<>(labels);
    assertThat(labels, contains(sorted));

    Assert.assertTrue(sortedList.equals(obtainedList));
```

OUTPUT

No.[5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 19, 22, 92, 96, 98, 99]  [10, 11, 12, 19, 22, 5, 7, 8, 92, 96, 98, 99] Column is display in  Ascending order

Sorting is not working due to single and double digit number. 
IF I convert to String Array to int will that work? how can I fix this code ?

Comment: You have already got the solution, why didn't you try it? I have no means but I want to say you should try to solve it by yourself at first, it's not a difficult problem, I think you can handle it.

Comment: @AlexDing I tried it but unable to solve please help after below comment still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can project from `List<String>` to `List<Integer>` via `stream#map` and then `stream#sorted` to sort the elements and then finally collect to a list.

```
List<Integer> result = obtainedList.stream()
                                   .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                   .sorted() // sort the elements
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or a typical for loop:

```
List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : obtainedList) 
        sortedList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
Collections.sort(sortedList); //sort the list after accumulating all the elements
```

Comment: this work but my assert fail  java.lang.AssertionError: Lists differ at element [0]: 5 != 5 expected [5] but found [5] how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it will work if you convert `obtainedList` to `List<Integer>`.

```
List<Integer> obtainedList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    obtainedList.add(RandomUtils.nextInt(100));
}

Collections.reverse(obtainedList);
Collections.sort(obtainedList);

System.out.print(obtainedList);
```

[image]

Comment: I get error "The method nextInt() in the type RandomUtils is not applicable for the arguments (int)" how can I solve this ?